# Unanswered and Interesting tags not working right

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

When I'm in the Unanswered Tab and click on a tag in Interesting Tags it takes me back to questions instead of adding it to the Unanswered Tags link.

Link of c++ in the normal tagbar:
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%2b%2b

Link of c++ in my Interesting Tags:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b

Using Firefox 3.6.12  on windows 7 64bit system

There is now a feature request open for this:
[Unanswered Tab and Interesting Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69773/unanswered-tab-and-interesting-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is the correct and intended behavior. If you want something different, then you want a feature request. Never heard this one before though.

Comment: The thinking was that if I go to Unanswered tab and then only want to use my intresting tags on the unanswered questions that it should stay in the selected tab and not jump back to questions.  Must I repost as a feature request or just add the tag and remove the bug tag??