# Unanswered Tab and Interesting Tags

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, tag-watching

The thinking was that if I go to Unanswered tab and then only want to use my interesting tags on the unanswered questions that it should stay in the selected tab and not jump back to questions.  This will help with building filters from your interesting tags:

This is how the related tags works:

Link of first tag in the related tags:

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%2b%2b

Link of second click on another tag in the related tags after first click:

> https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%2b%2b stl

So the request is for interesting tags clicks to have the same behavior when in Unanswered tab, of course this then works with a first click and second click on tags from your interesting bar or even a possibility that you can click on a tag in your interesting tags then click on a normal tag in the related tags.

Currently the interesting tags throws you back to Questions tab instead of staying in Unanswered tab

Comment: +1 for having both Unanswered and Unanswered in my favs, but I believe that the question lists are cached, and this list would not be cachable, causing a serious increase to the servers loads.